# Undocumented ProcessEventsFlag enums in QT

Tags: qt, event-handling, qt4, event-loop, qeventloop

I noticed that modal dialogs on QT uses a local QEventLoop with the ProcessEventFlags set as "DialogExec"

```
eventLoop.exec(QEventLoop::DialogExec);
```

The QT assistant has no information on what this enum means. There is another one called EventLoopExec. Anyone has any idea what they actually mean and why aren't they documented?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did some poking around and this is what I found:

- This enum is intentionally omitted from the documentation, along with several other QEventLoop::ProcessEventsFlag enum values (X11ExcludeTimers, ExcludeUserInput, WaitForMore, EventLoopExec) as there is an `\omitvalue` in front of each one in the comments that generate the docs.
- There is only one place in all of Qt that actually uses it, in `qeventdispatcher_mac.mm` in which it appears to be some kind of mac-specific optimization according to the in-line comments

The intentional omission of these values from the docs leads me to conclude that they're for internal Qt use only, and that you shouldn't need to use them or worry about them.

Comment: Hmm. Looks like that. I was taking a deep dive into how the QEventLoop is implemented for Modal Dialogs and I came across this.